# Linking against a versioned .so without SONAME

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, symlink, elf

I have a closed-source library that comes in a file named `libfoo.so.1.2.3.4`. `objdump -p` shows it doesn't have `SONAME` but does have `RPATH=/usr/local/lib`.

Is it a bad practice? Should I try to push the library authors to change the options?

How am I supposed to link my code against it? I don't want to change any system-wide configuration or pollute directories writable by only `root`.

I created a dummy `a.c` file with an empty `main()` and trying to link with `gcc a.c -L. -lfoo`. It fails. If I create `libfoo.so -> libfoo.1.2.3.4.so` symlink by hand and set `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd)` it works and `ldd` says `libfoo.so => {correct path}`.

So it kind of works, but is it the recommended way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it a bad practice?

Not by itself, no. However, it's likely that the library authors are *clueless*, especially  if you followed their installation procedure, and ended up with `libfoo.so.1.2.3.4`, but *no* symlink.

> Should I try to push the library authors to change the options?

Possibly. Not setting `SONAME` and setting `RPATH` aren't bad by themselves, but not providing a symlink certainly is.

> set `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd)`

That is generally a bad idea. You should prefer to encode the correct `RPATH` into the binary (and *only* the binary) which uses the library. On Linux, you can achieve that with `-Wl,--rpath=$(pwd)`.